# Como usar o bootstrap para websites com layout maior?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout-responsivo

Bom, eu sempre desenvolvi websites com bootstrap e nunca modifiquei o tamanho padrão do container que é de 1170px porque nunca houve necessidade. Agora tenho um layout de 1900 de largura.

Também uso sempre a sequencia **col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12**

Qual o procedimento correto para adaptar o **container** ao tamanho do meu layout? Tenho que usar o **-lg-** para desenvolver websites cujo a tela é maior que 1200px?

Comment: Acho que tem de sobrepor os seus css ao do bootstrap no container. `container{max-width:1900px;width:100%}`, só isso deve resolver. Certifique-se que os seus css são chamados a seguir aos do bootstrap

Comment: Tente usar a class container-fluid ao invés de container.

Answer (score 1):

Use a biblioteca BootstrapXL (extra large ou extra grande).

É apropriada para telas com mais de 1600px de largura.

Link do GitHub: [**BootstrapXL**](https://github.com/marcvannieuwenhuijzen/BootstrapXL)

Comment: Colocando esta biblioteca, o layout já vai se ajustar as grandes telas e é só eu continuar a fazer como já estou fazendo?

Comment: Você tem que adicionar as classes CSS dele! `col-xl` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Se quiser modificar o layout apenas para telas grandes, pode adicionar em seu CSS o seguinte:

@media screen and (min-width: 1980px){
    .container{
        width: 1900px;
    }
}

A largura é 1980px é arbitrária. Eu coloquei este valor, mas você pode colocar outros. O ideal é que seja maior que 1900px, pra dar uma "folga" para o container.

Adicione esta regra em outro CSS para sobrepor o do Bootstrap. Não é aconselhável alterar o próprio arquivo do Bootstrap.